# exerb -> What I did bad?

Tags: ruby

I'm try to compile simple `puts "hello world"` program by the `exerb` gem file.

mkexy test.rb => It's work's
exerb test.exy => It's doesn't work

What did I do wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/exerb.bat:196:in `<main>'
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/exerb.bat:67:in `main'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/exerb/recipe.rb:85:in `create_archive'
        2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/exerb/recipe.rb:85:in `each'
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/exerb/recipe.rb:86:in `block in create_archive'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/exerb/recipe.rb:146:in `add_file_entry': test.exy: no such file -- C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `test.exy` is not a Ruby file and therefore the error is thrown. Gems are only supported for the Ruby ecosystem. Not sure why you're trying to accomplish with `exy` but that won't work.